# Unity & Alternatives to non-convex collider + non-kinematic rigidbody

Tags: unity, rigidbody, meshcollider

I am working on a voxel game, where everything is one or more chunks of voxels (16x16x16). 
As voxels can be destroyed the chunk and collision area changes and can of course become non convex.
So to get collisions I put a non convex mesh collider on the chunk.
This is fine and works for my terrain as there is no rigidbody on the object.

Now my player object also consists of chunks of voxels, and everything which applies to my landscape, also applies to my player object (destroyable, needs non convex collider), but I also want my player object to be driven by physics, collisions resolved by physics and so on.
So it needs a rigidbody.

But Unity5 doesn't allow non-convex collider with non-kinematic rigidbodies.
So what are my options?

My requirements again: Everything driven by physics + collisions with destroyable non convex geometry...

Comment: good question, leaving comment for seeing answer for it.

Comment: In the Physics overview section of the documentation it recommends this "With careful positioning and sizing, compound colliders can often approximate the shape of an object quite well while keeping a low processor overhead". There are many limitations and special cases that need to be understood when working with Mesh Colliders that move. Also, using compound colliders could make things easier. With the mesh collider you'd have to figure what part of the model the collision occurred at. With a compound collider, simple "the right hand collider was hit by something".